# Why performance and speed of my tensorflow matrix factorization code is slower than numpy code?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I am unfamiliar tensorflow. 
I am trying to replace matrix factorization numpy code with tensorflow. But not only the model performance but also the speed is worse than numpy. What's wrong with my code?

Tensorflow code : https://github.com/choco9966/Research/blob/master/Matrix%20Factorization/%5BTensorflow%5D%20MatrixFactorization.ipynb

Based numpy code : https://github.com/choco9966/Research/blob/master/Matrix%20Factorization/%5BNumpy%5D%20MatrixFactorization.ipynb